# Authenticating user trying to access TFS2010 through webform on remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, tfs

I have made a webform that inserts work items to a tfs 2010server. On the tfs server I need to be able to see which user created the work item. If I run the webform code locally on my machine this works, because my machine is logged in to my user on the tfs server. But after deploying the code on a server I get a (401) unauthorized error message if I don't hardcode in my credentials like this

```
TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer = new TfsConfigurationServer(configurationServerUri, new NetworkCredential(user, pwd, domain));
```

(Locally the code below works)

```
TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer = new TfsConfigurationServer(configurationServerUri);
```

Is it possible to tell the webserver which user is logged into the machine accessing the webform, or is it any way I can prompt the user for username/password when he/she submits the webform?

thx for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you need to do and approach this issue

First most likely you have anonymous authentication allowed for your website. Meaning users can access your site without any restrictions and wont need to provide any information. Webserver doesn't know who they are. This will need to be disabled as by your question you need their info. You web app will try to connect to tfs under the webservers identity - either the dedicated account running the application pool or computer account.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770966(v=ws.10).aspx

The most simplest method is to enable basic authentication for your website, this will request users to provide username and password, downside is this method transmits data in base64 plain text, as such you channel must be secure
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009(v=ws.10).aspx
Forms authentication will allow you to use custom form to collect login info from users, and validate it yourself but works much like basic authentication

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753252(v=ws.10).aspx

If clients are users in your domain and application is used in intranet the best option is to use Windows authentication, it will try to automatically get users identity from domain, and will issue popup if that fails. Depending how your servers are setup getting this to work may be as easy as enabling it (tfs and your app on the same server) or require configuring your domain controllers for kerberous.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx

Once users are in have been authenticated you must make the webserver impersonate them when your code calls tfs. Complexity again depends on your setup.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708(v=ws.10).aspx

Alternativly you can use tfs impersonation to get similar result, this can be also used if for example you dont have users in tfs for each user connecting but instead want to impersonate and ClientCompany, Project or Team account

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulking/archive/2010/11/04/using-the-new-tfs-2010-impersonation-apis.aspx